# Crowdsourced Translation

Tags: internationalization, translation, community-translations

I once saw a free translation management software that was used to publish the original software texts and allow translation to other languages in a collaborative way. Something similar to http://www.mtranslator.com/ but also allowed community driven additional translations.

I just cannot seem to find it again so I was wondering if anyone knows of it?
Cheers

Comment: That's an interesting question but you'll likely get more answers if you don't limit the public to developers (as on this site). The question should move to a more general site ( http://superuser.com ) by itself in a few minutes.

Comment: I think it works only if you can find enough crows.

Comment: :) i noticed the spelling mistake, my bad...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Transifex](http://transifex.org/) is one such solution.

Comment: That's the one that does the job!

Comment: update: transifex.org now hosts the open source project used by transifex, the actual service is on http://transifex.net/

Comment: @futtta: That's how it's always been.

Comment: update: The open source project is no longer maintained: "Transifex used to be maintained as an open-source project on the side of Transifex.com. Since mid 2012, this repository is no longer actively maintained in favor of working aggressively in extending Transifex.com itself."

Answer (score 10):

[OneSky](http://www.oneskyapp.com/) also offers free crowdsourced translation solutions for public project. It supports 30+ popular file formats (such as .strings, .xml, .resx, .resjson, .rrc, .yml, .yaml, .properties, .po, .pot).

There are some features that can improve the quality of collaborative translation process.

1. glossary system (to ensure consistency)
2. voting system (where users can vote for their favorite translation)
3. validation system (e.g. length limitation, placeholders validation)
4. screenshot function (websites often contain short phrases, e.g. buttons, that would be hard for users to understand the context if no screenshots are provided)
5. system to monitor users' contribution (e.g. recognize dedicated users & blacklist users who are purposely causing damage to the project)
   translation memory

Other than crowdsourced translation, you can also hire pros / manage your own in-house translators using OneSky platform, so you can easily use a mix of those methods (e.g. hire pros to translate urgent things that needs speed and open up for users to review afterwards).

Importing & downloading of files is easy. Simply upload your resource files to our cloud-based platform / hook up with our API to automate the process.

Disclaimer: I am an employee at OneSky

Comment: Thank you Patrick for having shared this link ! It's really nice !

Comment: I'm trying it, it's the only platform that seems to import **hierarchical JSON**, splited in multiple files. It's been good so far.

Comment: The ability to import hierarchical JSON is indeed impressive.  And the support of `string-array` in the strings.xml (both importing into a flat format in the translation tool and then magically exporting back into the `string-array`... except for a little hiccup I'm experiencing with the order of array items).  Kudos to OneSky.

Answer (score 8):

[zanata](http://zanata.org/) is a nice web based translating platform.

Supported by RedHat, it a good choice for open source software.

And it's open source, so you can host it in your own company.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike other translation crowdsourcing websites, [Ackuna.com](http://Ackuna.com) is completely FREE. It supports the following string formats making developer's job easier:

1. Microsoft Excel (.xls)
2. Microsoft Office Open XML (.xlsx)
3. Android XML (.xml)
4. Ruby YAML (.yml)
5. Blackberry Resource (.rrc)
6. iOS Strings (.strings)
7. Java configuration (.properties)
8. Gnu Gettext Protable Object (.po)
9. Microsoft Word (.docx)
10. Adobe Acrobat (.pdf)
11. Text (.txt)

Answer (score 4):

[Lingumania](http://lingumania.com/) is also free and has great support for crowdsourcing. What it does, it scans the pages you want to have translated and then let's your community translate directly from the copy of the web page itself. The nice thing is that while translating you are able to see how the page will look like (helps a lot when trying out different synonyms to fit inside a fixed width of a button).

Answer (score 3):

There are several projects in this direction with varying focus. Do you know http://globalvoicesonline.org/lingua/ for example?

Comment: Yup, i came across it when searching. However, it does not really fit the scenario I had in mind:
1)let's say I have a website or a piece of software X in english
2)I upload my XML with all labels and texts to the site http://Y.com/
3)I add a link on my website X to the translation service, specifically to translate my website http://Y.com/X
4)someone from Bolivia likes my software and starts using it
5)they can always go to the URL http://Y.com/X and translate my website or software to Spanish or improve it

I saw this online service Y somewhere and it kills me that i can't find it again...

Answer (score 2):

The [World Wide Lexicon Project](http://www.worldwidelexicon.org/s/essay.html) may be what you're looking for. They publish a [Firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13897) for users to translate and correct machine translations of any site.

As a [publisher](http://www.worldwidelexicon.org/s/publishers.html), you can also request translations of your site. They also have an API.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.SiteTran.com is a free translation system which would work well for utilizing your users (the crowd). And it is run as a service, so the installation is very simple. You install a single line of JavaScript. It also enables SEO friendly URLs. It's my project, by the way.